# Bash, how to iterate through an array once & append to end of line?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, append

I am tasked with writing a script that analyzes code and attaches a comment with `#Loop`n or `#Selection n` that corresponds with the correct statements.

```
echo "enter full file name: "
read file

getArray(){
  arr=()
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    arr+=("$line")
  done < "$1"
}

getArray $file

echo "What file looks like before editing"
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" #Test function to see if array works (it does)


#Declare variables
x=1
y=1

#Start main loop
for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ ));
do
  if [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "while" ]] || [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "until" ]]
  then sed -i 's/$/ #Loop'$x'/' $file && let "x++"
       continue
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "for" ]]
  then sed -i 's/$/ #Loop'$x'/' $file && let "x++"
       continue
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "break" ]] || [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "done" ]]
  then sed -i 's/$/ #Loop'$x'/' $file && let "x--"
       continue
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "if" ]] || [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "case" ]]
  then sed -i 's/$/ #Selection'$y'/' $file && let "y++"
       continue
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "fi" ]] || [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "esac" ]]
  then sed -i 's/$/ #Selection'$y'/' $file && let "y--"
       continue
  else
       continue
  fi
done < $file
```

Obviously I'm a newbie in bash, and my loop logic/language usage might be a bit wonky. Can anyone help? Right now the output makes it seem like I am iterating through the array more than once and Sed appends additional text per line.

In case it wasn't clear: each array element is a line of strings; if an array element contains `while || for || until` then it adds a `#loop n` and with each of the corresponding `break` or `done`, it adds the same `#loop n`. And likewise for `if` and `case` and `fi` `esac` except it adds `#selection n`.

Sample Input:

```
Before

Final=$(date -d "2016-12-15 14:00" "+%j")
while true ; do
  Today=$(date "+%j")
  Days=$((Final - Today))
  if (( Days >= 14 )) ; then
    echo party
  elif (( Days >= 2 )) ; then
    echo study
  elif (( Days == 1 )) ; then
    for Count in 1 2 3
      do
      echo panic
    done
  else
    break
  fi
  sleep 8h
done
```

Expected Output:

```
After

Final=$(date -d "2016-12-15 14:00" "+%j")
while true ; do   # loop 1
  Today=$(date "+%j")
  Days=$((Final - Today))
  if (( Days >= 14 )) ; then   # selection 1
    echo party
  elif (( Days >= 2 )) ; then
    echo study
  elif (( Days == 1 )) ; then
    for Count in 1 2 3   # loop 2
      do
      echo panic
    done   # loop 2
  else
    break
  fi   # selection 1
  sleep 8h
done   # loop 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Right now the output makes it seem like I am iterating through the array more than once and Sed appends additional text per line.

This is because the comment to be attached to one line is appended to each line of the file, since no line number is specified for the `sed` substitute commands in your script. There surely are more efficient solutions, but prepending the corresponding line number is sufficient.

Though your script is quite close to working, two more problems have to be addressed. One is that the `==` expressions you use to test for the keywords match only if the whole line contains nothing else than the keyword (not even leading space); to allow for indentation, `=~` with an appropriate regular expression is useful. The other problem is the counting of the nesting depth (including the simple, but special case of `break`, where the depth remains unchanged); this seems more easy if we start at depth `0`. So, your *main loop* could be:

```
x=0
y=0
#Start main loop
for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ ))
do let l=1+i    # line numbers start at 1
  if [[ "${arr[$i]}" =~ ^[$IFS]*(while|until|for) ]]
  then sed -i $l"s/$/ #Loop$((++x))/" $file
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" =~ ^[$IFS]*break ]]
  then sed -i $l"s/$/ #Loop$x/" $file # no x-- here!
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" =~ ^[$IFS]*done ]]
  then sed -i $l"s/$/ #Loop$((x--))/" $file
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" =~ ^[$IFS]*(if|case) ]]
  then sed -i $l"s/$/ #Selection$((++y))/" $file
  elif [[ "${arr[$i]}" =~ ^[$IFS]*(fi|esac) ]]
  then sed -i $l"s/$/ #Selection$((y--))/" $file
  fi
done <$file
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test this;

```
echo "enter full file name: "
read file

getArray(){
  arr=()
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    arr+=("$line")
  done < "$1"
}

getArray $file

echo "What file looks like before editing"
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" #Test function to see if array works (it does)


#Declare variables
x=1
y=1

#Start main loop
for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ ));
do
    #echo $i "====" ${arr[$i]}
    #echo "-------"
    #echo "x"$x
  if [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "while"* ]] || [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "until" ]]
  then 
       sed -i "$((i+1))s/$/ #Loop $x/" $file 
       let "x++"
       continue; 
   fi

  if [[ "${arr[$i]}" == *"for"* ]]
  then sed -i "$((i+1))s/$/ #Loop'$x'/" $file && let "x++"
       continue
   fi

  if [[ "${arr[$i]}" == *"done"* ]]
  then sed -i "$((i+1))s/$/ #Loop'$((x-1))'/" $file 
       continue
   fi

  if [[ "${arr[$i]}" == *"if"* ]] || [[ "${arr[$i]}" == *"case"* ]]
  then 
        if [[ "${arr[$i]}" != *"elif"* ]] 
        then 
            sed -i "$((i+1))s/$/ #Selection'$y'/" $file && let "y++"
        fi
        continue
       fi
  if [[ "${arr[$i]}" == *"fi"* ]] || [[ "${arr[$i]}" == *"esac"* ]]
  then sed -i "$((i+1))s/$/ #Selection'$((y-1))'/" $file
       continue
  fi


done < $file
```